# Javascript Form calculator

Tags: javascript

When I type values in the far right text boxes, then click "click to calculate" i want the values of all the text boxes to add up and display.  I cannot figure it out. when i click the click to calculate button, it does nothing. not a thing!

```
<SCRIPT>

function add()
{
var a = document.getElementById("fscf_field4_8").value;
var b = document.getElementById("fscf_field4_10").value;
var c = document.getElementById("fscf_field4_12").value;
var d = document.getElementById("fscf_field4_14").value;
var e = document.getElementById("fscf_field4_16").value;
document.getElementById("fscf_field4_19").value =a+b+c+d+e;
}
</script>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="FSContact4" style="width:375px;">
<form action="/payment/#FSContact4" id="fscf_form4" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="fscf_submitted" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="fs_postonce_4" value="99193296484a8d52d2b9579199ca2f0c,1384214867">
<input type="hidden" name="si_contact_action" value="send">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="4">

<div id="fscf_required4">
  <span style="text-align:left;">*</span> <span style="text-align:left;">indicates required field</span>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="mailto_id" value="1">

<div id="fscf_div_clear4_4" style="clear:both;">
  <div id="fscf_div_field4_4" style="clear:left; float:left; width:99%; max-width:550px; margin-right:10px;">
    <div id="fscf_label4_4" style="text-align:left; padding-top:5px;">
      <label style="text-align:left;" for="fscf_field4_4">Company Name<span style="text-align:left;">*</span></label>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      <input style="text-align:left; margin:0;" type="text" id="fscf_field4_4" name="company-name" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="fscf_div_clear4_5" style="clear:both;">
  <div id="fscf_div_field4_5" style="clear:left; float:left; width:99%; max-width:550px; margin-right:10px;">
    <div id="fscf_label4_5" style="text-align:left; padding-top:5px;">
      <label style="text-align:left;" for="fscf_field4_5">Person Doing the Transaction<span style="text-align:left;">*</span></label>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      <input style="text-align:left; margin:0;" type="text" id="fscf_field4_5" name="person-doing-the-transaction" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="fscf_div_clear4_6" style="clear:both;">
  <div id="fscf_div_field4_6" style="clear:left; float:left; width:99%; max-width:550px; margin-right:10px;">
    <div id="fscf_label4_6" style="text-align:left; padding-top:5px;">
      <label style="text-align:left;" for="fscf_field4_6">email<span style="text-align:left;">*</span></label>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      <input style="text-align:left; margin:0;" type="text" id="fscf_field4_6" name="email01" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table border="1" bordercolor="#FFCC00" style="background-color:#FFFFCC" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
                <td>Invoice Number</td>
                <td>Amount (USD)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_7 name="Invoice Number 1"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_8 name="Amount 1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_9 name="Invoice Number 2"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_10 name="Amount 2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_11 name="Invoice Number 3"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_12 name="Amount 3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_13 name="Invoice Number 4"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_14 name="Amount 4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_15 name="Invoice Number 5"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_16 name="Amount 5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="click" value="Click to Calculate" onclick="add();"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_19"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<div id="fscf_submit_div4" style="text-align:left; padding-top:2px;">
                <input type="submit" id="fscf_submit4" style="cursor:pointer; margin:0;" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
</div>
</tr>
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: And I'm sorry If i'm not typing my question in proper order or something, I'm new to the site, I'm trying to post the question in the right method, without offending anyone.  I'm not very good at javascript and have no idea what I'm doing! : ( I'm really trying!

Comment: Everyone in your class is using this site for their homework. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968825/javascript-to-pick-up-values-in-a-form-text-box

Comment: @user2990466 what did you try?

Comment: First of all, html syntax is wrong almost everywhere. http://jsfiddle.net/6AYFg/

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you forgot to close the quotation marks of all the IDs of inputs. Try doing it. 
i.e.

```
<input type="text" id="fscf_field4_8 name="Amount 1">
```

needs to be:

```
<input type="text" id="fscf_field4_8" name="Amount 1">
```

Also you need to add parseInt() when you parsing string's int value. below i put the new code snippet 
**Confirmation:** Just tried your code with proper quotation marks and intParse(),it works

Your final code for integer parse:

```
<SCRIPT>

function add()
{
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("fscf_field4_8").value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("fscf_field4_10").value);
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("fscf_field4_12").value);
    var d = parseInt(document.getElementById("fscf_field4_14").value);
    var e = parseInt(document.getElementById("fscf_field4_16").value);
    document.getElementById("fscf_field4_19").value =a+b+c+d+e;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should always specify the radix when using _Number.parseInt(string, radix)_.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the id value of your `table` properly.

**Error:**`<input type="text" id="fscf_field4_7 name="Invoice Number 1">`
There is no closing Quotes for id value(`fscf_field4_7`)
 above. try to close id value if all TextBox's properly.

Replace your `table` with following:

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="#FFCC00" style="background-color:#FFFFCC" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
                <td>Invoice Number</td>
                <td>Amount (USD)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_7" name="Invoice Number 1"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_8" name="Amount 1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_9" name="Invoice Number 2"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_10" name="Amount 2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_11" name="Invoice Number 3"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_12" name="Amount 3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_13" name="Invoice Number 4"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_14" name="Amount 4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_15" name="Invoice Number 5"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_16" name="Amount 5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="click" value="Click to Calculate" onclick="add()"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_19"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this working sample http://jsfiddle.net/6AYFg/

Properly close all your tags and attributes first

parse values from all elements to int

```
<td><input type="text" id="fscf_field4_7 name="Invoice Number 1"></td>
```

> 

```
function add()
{
var a = document.getElementById("fscf_field4_8").value;
var b = document.getElementById("fscf_field4_10").value;
var c = document.getElementById("fscf_field4_12").value;
var d = document.getElementById("fscf_field4_14").value;
var e = document.getElementById("fscf_field4_16").value;
document.getElementById("fscf_field4_19").value =a+b+c+d+e;
}
```